# Duty free without flying?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, duty-free

Am I allowed to buy a cheap flight one way for 15$ just so that i can get through security in order to use duty free. Is that legal? And am I allowed to leave the airport without boarding my flight. If so, is there a way for me to cancel so that the flight wont wait for me?

Comment: No, you're not allowed to do that. And flights don't wait for late passengers!

Comment: No, though the exact details depend a lot on the country and sometimes the airport. Can you clarify which country and airport you are referring to (and which destination from that airport which you could fly to for $15...).

Comment: It is legal (but on some airports prohibited [company policies]), but you must pay duties at custom. When you pass the custom (so entering in the custom zone of your country), it is your duty to pay taxes if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed. Airports make tight checks.

In most airports, you have to pass emmigration and customs and then only can buy duty free items. In USA and some other countries, they will deliver the items just before you board the flight.

If for any reason, you want to exit from the emmigration, without making travel, you will be most likely asked to let go of the goods.